# pyodbc connection with Cloudera Impala fails on colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, cloudera, pyodbc, impala

I've installed pyodbc and configured system ODBC. Anything else I should configure?

```
pyodbc.autocommit=True
conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=Cloudera Impala DSN", autocommit=True)
print("pass")
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to configure an ODBC DSN before you can use it, or use alternative way to supply connection parameters to pyodbc. https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/other/connectors/impala-odbc/latest/Cloudera-ODBC-Driver-for-Impala-Install-Guide.pdf

Comment: [why-not-upload-images-of-code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: i've already configured ODBC

Comment: Maybe you think you did, but "Data source name not found..." means your notebook thinks otherwise.

Comment: @mazaneicha I uploaded a snapshot of my system DSN config

Comment: Is that a snapshot of Windows DSN? The error mentions _"unixODBC"_ so I'd assume your notebook doesn't run on win.

Comment: Is the test connection succeeding?

Comment: @koushiksinharoy it is

Comment: did you try like below answer? in your connection string, i can see quote is misplaced. not sure if thats a typo or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use - `conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN="Cloudera Impala DSN", autocommit=True)`
  We use
`cfg = {'DSN': 'Cloudera Impala DSN', 'host': 'xx.com', 'port': 1234,'username': 'uu', 'password': 'pp'}
conn_string='DSN=%s;  database='default';AuthMech=3;UseSASL=1; UID=%s; PWD=%s; SSL=1;AllowSelfSignedServerCert=1;CAIssuedCertNamesMismatch=1' %(cfg['DSN'], cfg['username'], cfg['password'])
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string, autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()`